# If I accept an answer on my question, remind me I can upvote it as well

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, up-votes, popups

If I upvote an answer on my question, I am reminded that I can accept the answer. If I accept an answer on my question, there should be a prompt to *upvote* the answer.

Comment: Accepting an answer is a critical part of the QA lifecycle. Upvoting one is not.